# Install a Apache/MySQL/PHP web application locally

Tags: windows, apache, installation, uac, windows-firewall

We have a web application that is based on Apache, MySQL and PHP. I want to make that available as a desktop application for windows also, installed via MSI. A small .NET application starts a modified xampp package that we deploy and then opens an embedded Chromium-based browser.

Questions:

- How do I ensure that I am able to modify the Apache/MySQL/PHP config on run time? The files are stored in Program Files, and UAC of course does not allow me to change them without "Run as administrator". Is there a way to make these files editable during setup? Otherwise I would have to figure out how to start Apache/MySQL with custom config files from a temp directory.
- How do I tell the installer to add Apache & MySQL to the firewall exception list, or how do I tell the firewall that applications that listen only locally are not a threat?

Comment: if i understand correctly, are you trying to distribute a web application as windows installer package?

Comment: Correct. Server and Client as a one-click-distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized I do not want a dirty hack here and tried to do it "right":

- I modified the configuration of Apache and MySQL so that everything that changes lies in %APPDATA%. The configuration files are passed as command line arguments.
- The current version of [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) allows Firewall rules to be set on installation.

Actually it wasn't that hard to change the config as I thought it would be and I learned some bits in the process...

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how this might be helpful, but take a look at inno setup it's free tool to deploy software, and it allow to make custom installation script using pascal, by putting some effort i hope , you can install wamp, add firewall restrictions etc.

Comment: The installation is done already, it installs o.k., but I have to use "Start as Administrator" on the tool so it can change files in program files and the firewall asks me whether to allow the 2 servers. I want to get rid of all this.

Comment: you can disable uac in control panel, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-za/windows-vista/turn-user-account-control-on-or-off  , for fire wall exception you can use batch files , or you can use windows powershell file. if you are fluent in .net programming language you can use them as well.